# I receive a lint error over the context API default state that consists only of functions?

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I receive this lint warning over the following code: the idea here is that the auth provider's default state consists of functions that are implemented later down the code

> src\context\auth\AuthProvider.tsx
> Line 76:17:   Unexpected empty method 'Signup'                                                                              @typescript-eslint/no-empty-function
> Line 77:17:   Unexpected empty method 'Signin'                                                                              @typescript-eslint/no-empty-function
> Line 78:18:   Unexpected empty method 'SignOut'                                                                             @typescript-eslint/no-empty-function
> Line 79:22:   Unexpected empty method 'UpdateEmail'                                                                         @typescript-eslint/no-empty-function
> Line 80:32:   Unexpected empty method 'SendRestPasswordEmail'                                                               @typescript-eslint/no-empty-function
> Line 81:23:   Unexpected empty method 'RestPassword'                                                                        @typescript-eslint/no-empty-function
> Line 82:29:   Unexpected empty method 'UpdatePremiumUntil'                                                                  @typescript-eslint/no-empty-function
> Line 83:23:   Unexpected empty method 'DeletAccount'                                                                        @typescript-eslint/no-empty-function

```js
interface AuthState {
  Signup: (email: string, password: string, userType: string, privacySettings: PrivacySettings) => void;
  Signin: (email: string, password: string) => void;
  SignOut: (actionType: SignOutAction) => void;
  UpdateEmail: (newEmail: string) => void;
  SendRestPasswordEmail: (email: string) => void;
  RestPassword: (oobCode: string, newPassword: string) => void;
  UpdatePremiumUntil: () => void;
  DeletAccount: (
    userType: UsersTypes,
    uid: string,
    password: string,
    clientsIds: string[],
    profileImage: boolean,
    customEquipmentObject: { customData: string[] }
  ) => void;
}

const defaultState: AuthState = {
  Signup: () => {},
  Signin: () => {},
  SignOut: () => {},
  UpdateEmail: () => {},
  SendRestPasswordEmail: () => {},
  RestPassword: () => {},
  UpdatePremiumUntil: () => {},
  DeletAccount: () => {},
};

// later on 

 // Signup with email and password
  const Signup = async (email: string, password: string, userType: string, privacySettigns: PrivacySettings) => {
  // the implementations 
  }
  
  // rest of the functions..
```

Answer (score 0):

If you must have empty functions you should add an explanation as to why they're empty. The rule is there because:

> Empty functions can reduce readability because readers need to guess whether it’s intentional or not. So writing a clear comment for empty functions is a good practice.

See https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-empty-function#rule-details

I would use

```
const emptyFunction = () => {
  // Default value for no behavior
  // This way callers don't need to check if a function is defined.
}; 

const defaultState: AuthState = {
  Signup: emptyFn
  Signin: emptyFn,
  SignOut: emptyFn,
  UpdateEmail: emptyFn,
  SendRestPasswordEmail: emptyFn,
  RestPassword: emptyFn,
  UpdatePremiumUntil: emptyFn,
  DeletAccount: emptyFn,
};
```

However, your empty functions don't really match the AuthState definition, so your code looks wrong. You should update each empty function to have the right parameters and add the `// Default value is no behavior`

Comment: my instance is strange since i use the auth provider to handle auth yet i still have to declare initial types..

Comment: @Richardson Sorry, I don't understand if there's a question in your comment or how I can improve the answer.

Answer (score -2):

Disable linter rules temporarily then: https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/rules#disabling-rules

Comment: Instead, you should document why the functions are empty. Please read the rule before making blanket suggestions. See https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-empty-function#rule-details "Rule Details:"
This rule is aimed at eliminating empty functions. A function will not be considered a problem if it contains a comment."

Comment: I can't see any meaningful difference between a justifying rule-disabling comment and the same comment used as a rule fullfillment. In this case rule-disabling comment will be more concise and could handle all those empty implementations at once.

Comment: well I use lint for this .... to fish out issues.

Comment: Why would the OP have added this rule, then? The rule explains itself, I gave you the explanation and you're still doubling down on disabling it?

Comment: Also, assuming the OP didn't know how to disable a rule is pretty naïve. Your answer should at best be a comment (which I myself would not add).

Comment: That's good OP uses those rules, so I only advised to disable it _temporarily_. There are a lot of rules that usually help to catch issues but are sometimes "overambitious" and I can't see any *functional* difference between both mentioned methods of silencing it.

Comment: Disabling the ESLint rule for a specific line will suppress the warning, but it doesn't provide any context or explanation for why the function is empty.  For example, is this a mocked function with no behavior? Is this a default empty implementation so that callers don't have to check if a function is defined? Is it to be used in a conditional event handler for code clarity in a case where you want nothing to happen? Is it a JS abstract method?

Comment: Encoragement to provide justification is the second bullet point under the link I provided.